# How do I enable Feature/Permissions Policy in an iframe in Google Add-ons?

Tags: google-apps-script, iframe, google-workspace-add-ons, http-permissions-policy

I am trying use a feature policy, serial, in my google add-on. I am having difficulty trying to enable this particular feature policy inside an iframe, mainly I believe is because the parent iframes don't have it enabled. Below is what the iframe DOM tree looks like. I don't have access to "sandboxFrame" and "userHtmlFrame" directly, so I cannot change its allowed features. Even if I set 'serial' in the most child iframe, I cannot find the 'serial' feature enabled in its featurePolicy.

```
<iframe id="sandboxFrame" allow="accelerometer *; ambient-light-sensor *; autoplay *; camera *; clipboard-read *; clipboard-write *; encrypted-media *; fullscreen *; geolocation *; gyroscope *; magnetometer *; microphone *; midi *; payment *; picture-in-picture *; screen-wake-lock *; speaker *; sync-xhr *; usb *; web-share *; vibrate *; vr *" sandbox="allow-downloads allow-forms allow-modals allow-popups allow-popups-to-escape-sandbox allow-same-origin allow-scripts" src="https://...-script.googleusercontent.com/...">
    <iframe id="userHtmlFrame" allow="accelerometer *; ambient-light-sensor *; autoplay 
    *; camera *; clipboard-read *; clipboard-write *; encrypted-media *; fullscreen *; 
    geolocation *; gyroscope *; magnetometer *; microphone *; midi *; payment *; picture- 
    in-picture *; screen-wake-lock *; speaker *; sync-xhr *; usb *; web-share *; vibrate 
    *; vr *" src="/blank" title="">
       <iframe id="myIframe" allow="serial *;" sandbox="allow-forms allow-modals allow-popups allow-presentation allow-same-origin allow-scripts" src="...external website in          
          GitHub Pages">
       ...
       </iframe>
    </iframe>
</iframe>
```

If anyone acquainted with google add-ons can prove me wrong about anything that would be great. I would appreciate any kind of help.

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Yes, you can pass any permission into nested iframe **only** if parent context [has](https://csplite.com/fp/test199/#no_FP) that permission granted.
   Keep in mind that when passing permissions the origin will be changed accordingly, i.e:

`<iframe scr='https://example.com' allow="fullscreen 'self'">`
     `// the permission for fullscreen is 'self' (== http://example.com)`
     `// but main thing is this is that iframe HAS that permission, therefore`
     `// it can grant it to any nested context with ANY origin:`
   `<iframe src='https://www.youtube.com' allow="fullscreen https://www.youtube.com">`
     `// will get permission of fullscreen mode for https://www.youtube.com origin`
   `</iframe>`
`</iframe>`

2. In the parent iframe the `serial` Feature Policy directive is not specified in the `allow='...'` attribute. That means this feature is allowed with the [default value](https://csplite.com/fp/#default) - `'src'`. Therefore parent iframe has implicitly permission for `serial`, so it can pass it into any nested iframe.
3. I hear nothing about the `serial` Feature Policy directive, is [it supported](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Feature-Policy#directives)?

Comment: Re: 2. Then passing serial to the child iframe should be working...yet the permission is not being granted. Any thoughts for why it's doing that?
Re: 3. serial is still in experimental stages, but it is supported by a select few browsers.

Comment: If I do document.allowedFeatures(), 'serial' is not included in the list. Yet 'serial' is included in document.features(). Is there any hope of enabling 'serial' in such a situation?

Comment: "'serial' is included in document.features()" - it's mean that `serial` is supported by browser. "If I do document.allowedFeatures(), 'serial' is not included in the list" - means `serial` is not permitted in current browsing context. Maybe top level document disallows it, maybe it's allowed in secure context only (https:). There is not any hope to allow it in nested browsing contexts in this case.